# Odd behavior of max and having in MySQL when max==0

Tags: mysql, having

I have the following table:

```
mysql> select * from foo;
| id | value | bar  |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 |     2 |    3 |
|  2 |     0 |    3 |
|  1 |     1 |    5 |
```

I want to select the tuple with the maximum `value` for each `id`. However, when `max(value)` is 0, I don't get a result.

```
mysql> select id,max(value),bar from foo group by id having max(value);
| id | max(value) | bar  |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 |          2 |    3 |
```

Is this supposed to behave like that and if so, why?

Comment: `select id,max(value) from foo group by id` is enough to get the max `value` per `id`. You don't need the `having clause`.

Comment: having max(value) is translated has having true or not 0.You probably want having max(value) = SELECT max(value) from t

Comment: Apart from that `having` doesn't behave the way you think, i.e. like *get me the record having the max `value`*. It rather checks whether the predicate used is true or not. In your case the predicate is simple `max(value)` which is equal to `0` in the first case. This is considered to be false in MySQL, so nothing is returned.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos You're completely right, but this is a simplified example. In my actual case, there is a join of two tables and there is another column that I need and it comes from the same record as the value column.

Comment: So, the comments from Giorgios or Mihai will serve here as answer.

Comment: You say *the tuple with the maximum value **for each** id.* But then only one record is returned. Whats happens to record with `id=2`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos That was exactly my question and your answer actually addresses that. What happens is that `max(value)` evaluates to false for id=2 and the record is not displayed.

Comment: @martinkunev I am glad I was able to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HAVING` cannot be used in any way to pick a record out of a group of records as defined by the fields used in the `GROUP BY` clause. It is rather applied to the group as a whole.

So, in your case, you have to do a self-join to get the rest of the table fields:

```
select t1.id, t1.value, t1...
from foo as t1
join (
   select id, max(value) as max_value
   from foo 
   group by id
) as t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.value = t2.max_value
```

Comment: This is not what I would have wanted to hear, but I'd have to deal with reality. In the real query I need to join only the records satisfying an `on` condition which depends on the first table in the select. Then I need to get the max of that and do the join again. It gets quite complicated but I'd need to live with that.

Comment: @martinkunev In another RDMBS like SQL Server, Oracle or Postgres you would have used `ROW_NUMBER` which makes things much simpler, but as of yet MySQL does not implement window functions.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can get MAX couple by multiplying (id x value).

```
create table foo(id int, value int);
insert into foo values
(2,0),
(1,0),
(2,1),
(3,0),
(2,2);

select id, value
from foo
order by (id * value) desc
limit 1;

id | value
 2 |  2

drop table foo;
```